# Detecting if the monitor is powered off

Tags: linux, monitor, nvidia

I have a kiosk type application and I need to be notified if the LCD TV is powered off so I can chastise someone.  I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with nVidia video cards and the nVidia drivers.  The TVs are plugged in via HDMI.

I've taken a look at `nvidia-settings -q ConnectedDisplays` and `nvidia-settings -q EnabledDisplays`, but both always report the monitor is connected.  I'm guessing that this value is only set once when the monitor is first powered on?

I've also looked at `xrandr --properties` and it always reports `default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm` regardless.

Where else can I look?

EDIT:  Max, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  At this point I've installed the `ddccontrol` package and I'm able to run `ddccontrol -p`.  If the monitor is turned on I receive a bunch of power, color and geometry values, and if the monitor is turned off it returns mostly empty.  I'm going to work on a little python script to parse it out.

Comment: You could also try at http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why have the power switch accessible at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3433203/176769

Comment: `ddccontrol` from that post didnt detect my monitor/tv changes but the `udevadm monitor --property` did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Determine if LCD Monitor is Turned on From Linux Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433203/how-to-determine-if-lcd-monitor-is-turned-on-from-linux-command-line)